# pandas: creating lagged variables of existing variable in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df with multiple time series variables. Say variable 'A', 'B', 'C' etc.

There have date as the index. How can I create 3,6 and 12 month lagged version in  a loop? I guess I could manually type for each variable like below, but was hoping if there is an efficient way to do it. Thanks.

```
df['A_3'] = df['A'].shift(3)
df['A_6'] = df['A'].shift(6)
df['A_12'] = df['A'].shift(12)

df['B_3'] = df['B'].shift(3)
df['B_6'] = df['B'].shift(6)
df['B_12'] = df['B'].shift(12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lag = [3,6,12]

for col in df.columns:
    for l in lag:
        df.loc[:,col+"_"+str(l)] = df[col].shift(l)
```

You can also use `itertools product` i.e

```
from itertools import product 

for col,lag  in product(df.columns,lags):
    df[col+'_'+str(lag)] = df[col].shift(lag)
```

Comment: can you post a reproducible code of data frame that I can use to test the code?

Comment: @Zenvega this answer is good. I have edited a bit hope that helps

Comment: @Dark the .loc part is good, it works, OP did not used it as it was provided he used `df.loc[col+"_"+str(l)]` instaed of `df.loc[:,col+"_"+str(l)]`

Comment: You know that `[:,` is easy to miss many times. Anyway there doesn't exist a column so I felt loc is bit extra.